# How to hide specific json object data using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I use a PHP file to parse json data as DIV objects, and below is the example of the results (in HTML)

```js
// hidethis.js
$('.hidden').click(function() {
    $('.agee').hide();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <h2>Data A</h2>
        <p class="agee">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
        <button type="button" class="hidden">Hide Age A</button>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <h2>Data B</h2>
        <p class="agee">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
        <button type="button" class="hidden">Hide Age B</button>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <h2>Data C</h2>
        <p class="agee">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
        <button type="button" class="hidden">Hide Age C</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Preview: https://jsfiddle.net/xj71kqgb/

My **problem** is when I clicked any "Hide" button, all `p.agee` are automatically hidden.

The **result** I'm trying to achieve, when the "Hide Age A" button is clicked, only the `p.agee` from Data A will be hidden.

And also if possible, without needed to touch the JS script when new data is being added. Is it possible to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes your code will hide all elements with class `.agee`.

You must change your code to this:

```js
$('.hidden').click(function() {
    $(this).closest("div.row").find(".agee").hide();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <h2>Data A</h2>
        <p class="agee">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
        <button type="button" class="hidden">Hide Age A</button>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <h2>Data B</h2>
        <p class="agee">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
        <button type="button" class="hidden">Hide Age B</button>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <h2>Data C</h2>
        <p class="agee">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
        <button type="button" class="hidden">Hide Age C</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

when you clicked on `.hidden` class. first must find closest `div.row` tag (parent div) then on this div you must find `.agee` and hide it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **toggle** function if you want show page again onclick

```js
$('.hidden').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('.row').find('.agee').toggle();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <h2>Data A</h2>
        <p class="agee">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
        <button type="button" class="hidden">Hide Age A</button>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <h2>Data B</h2>
        <p class="agee">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
        <button type="button" class="hidden">Hide Age B</button>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <h2>Data C</h2>
        <p class="agee">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
        <button type="button" class="hidden">Hide Age C</button>
    </div>
</div>
```